# How to reset a step counter daily?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a pedometer app. It is almost done, except for one thing. When day has past, I want to reset step numbers.How to implement `sharedpreferences` to my code?
How can I reset step numbers?
I tried this way. But when time past every numbers turning normal value. Not starting from zero.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor == stepCounter){
        stepCount = (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
        ////////////////
        saveSteps(stepCount);
        resetStep(stepCount);


        ////////////////
        progressBar.setProgress(stepCount);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(stepCount));
        txtstepinfo.setText("Adım: " +  String.valueOf(stepCount) );
        ///////////
        progressBar.setProgress(stepCount);
        Log.i("sda",String.valueOf(stepCount));
        /////////////////////
        txtcalinfo.setText("Kalori: "+calculateCalori(stepCount));
        txtDistanceinfo.setText("Mesafe: "+calculateDistance(stepCount));

    }

}


private void resetStep(int s){

    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();

    
    if(date.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0 && date.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 00 ){
        editor.putInt("step",0);
        editor.apply();
        stepCount = 0;
        txtstepinfo.setText(String.valueOf(stepCount));

    }


}
private void saveSteps(int s){
    editor.putInt("step",s);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope my answer make it clear, i'll correct your code.

```kotlin
if (date.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0 && date.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 00 ) {
        editor.putInt("step",0);
        editor.apply();
        stepCount = 0;
        txtstepinfo.setText(String.valueOf(stepCount));

    }
```

it means, this code is just running well when application opened at 00:00:00 - 59s. I have simple condition to reset your shared preferences, but i didn't expect it was the best answer.

```kotlin
val preferences by lazy { applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("KEY", MODE_PRIVATE) }
val calendar by lazy {Calendar.getInstance() }
val date by lazy { calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) } // 1 - 31
val dateKey = "DATE_NOW"
val stepKey = "STEP_COUNT"

// Check the date
if (preferences.getInt(dateKey, 0) != date) {
    // Clear shared preferences
    preferences.edit { clear() }
    // Persistent the date
    preferences.edit { putInt(dateKey, date) }
}

val myStep = preferences.getInt(stepKey, 0)
preferences.edit { putInt(stepKey, myStep + 1) }
```